# 'npm ci' command is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, node-modules, npm-ci

I have installed a library with version 1.0.0 and then I have modified package.json file with version 1.0.3 and then I run `"npm ci"` and expecting it should not update the package as it should refer package-lock.json file. But its updated the package to the latest version 1.4.4 in the node_modules.
Why it's happening like this?